# NSMutableDictionary representation for JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have one genuine question which I am facing at this point and I am sure someone might be able to help me.

I have a JSON Post which looks like:

```
{
"CustomerAccount":{
    "CustomerUID":"String content",
    "UserName":"String content",
    "Password":"String content",
    "OldPassword":"String content",
    "Email":"String content",
    "QuestionUID":2147483647,
    "QuestionAnswer":"String content",
    "EAlerts":true
    }
}
```

Now I have a dictionay which set's value of CustomerUID, UserName, etc.. Now if I want to bind a upper level to bind all that to CustomerAccount and send as my JSONRepresentation, is there any easier way than actually creating a new dictionary and setting a value of key "CustomerAccount" in this example? I am sure there might be a better way of doing that.

Thanks.

Comment: 'bind' doesn't have a specific meaning in this context - what do you mean by 'bind'?

Comment: well I just want to have another key "CustomerAccount" to go on top of my basic equation of the keys, the hierarchy as it is showed, at this point I just have the CustomerUID,UserName,etc not CustomerAccount. So to do this I have to create another dictionary with "CustomerAccount" and setValue of existing dictionary and then send to SBJSON to convert it to string and send. I hope you get what I am trying to say here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If you're having trouble explaining what you want in English, it's probably going to be easier if you write exactly how you want the data to look after it's converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure I follow, but is this what you want maybe:

```
NSDictionary *dictA = <dictionary_with_customeruid_etc>;
NSDictionary *customerAccountDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dictA, @"CustomerAccount", nil];
```

But I'm not sure I follow your question entirely so maybe you want something else. Please let us know a bit more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: matt you are right, that's what I want, but is there any other alternative way in JSONRepresentation that does the job, lets say if I have an object created of customerAccount, would that create the actual representation, as in java for android that seams to be the case.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. Do you have the code to create the JSON or not?

Comment: @kforkarim - did you sort this out? Any further questions?

Comment: matt I did happen to sort it out, thanks, I used your method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question but ill give it a try.
You can easily parse the JSON string to a NSDictionary using JSONKit https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit
JSONKit is a very fast and lightweight library and you can parse the string and get the wanted value like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
NSString *value = [dict valueForKey:@"key"];
```

To actually set a value in your JSON string you should use `rangeOfString: .location` to get the range if the existing value then `replaceOccurenciesOfString:[jsonString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(loc,len)] withString:VALUE`.